# Intercept recycler view gesture swipe right and left, android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I have a recyclerView. When the user swipes right or left perform some action.
Please note I am not asking for recycler view item swipe but whole recyclerview gesture left or right.

For that I extending the View.OnTouchListener and tried to get the gesture as below

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } /*else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }*/
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}


/*public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
*/
}
```

Then used it as

```
recyclerViewComponent.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(context){
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            super.onSwipeLeft();
        }
    });
```

But I am not getting the callback. What is wrong in this?

Comment: Have you made any progress so far?

Comment: @alex nopes I am still trying to figure out. If you have found a solution please do let me know.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion with inheriting `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @alex I tried but it doesn't work. I have a child recyclerview in parent recyclerview and I want to get swipe left/right on child recyclerview

Comment: Ok, have you made your own class extending the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @alex Yes for the child recycler view i am extending the class.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Google doc](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup) you have to use `onInterceptTouchEvent` when dealing with `ViewGroups` (`RecyclerView` extends `ViewGroup`). 
So you have to extend the `RecyclerView` class in order to override its `onTouchInterceptTouchEvent` method:

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev)) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
           [...]
          }
       }        
   }

}
```

Then you have to change your layout XML file as well to use your custom `RecyclerView` `MyRecyclerView`.

Alternatively you can adapt a solution involving 3rd party components / libraries like [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-Pull-to-Refresh-Guide#recyclerview-with-swiperefreshlayout) or [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView#swipe-detection).

Answer (score 0):

@alex response is the correct one but as workaround you can always return false in onFling() so the event will be dispatched to the childs.